# Weird program breakdown when e is used without a whitespace

Tags: c++

I'm having a really weird problem with this. The program is supposed to take the entered values, convert them into meters, find which is the largest and which is the smallest, sum them, and print all of the information at the end. It seems to work in every situation except when I add a value with an e as the unit, without white space. For example, it works if I press 5 'enter' e, but if I enter 5e it totally breaks down. It doesn't do this with other "wrong" units. Is there something special about e? (This programs is written for the chapter 4 drill in the Stroustrup programming book).

```
        #include<algorithm>
        #include<cmath>
        #include<iostream>
        #include<string>
        #include<vector>
        using namespace std;
        inline void keep_window_open() {char ch; cin >> ch;}


        double cm_m(double x) //cm to m
        {
            return x/100;   
        }
        double in_m(double x) //in to m
        {
            return (x*2.54)/100.0;
        }
        double ft_m(double x) //ft to m
        {
            return (((x*12))*2.54)/100;
        }

        int main()
        {
            int z=0;
            double init=0;
            int w=1;
            string unit;
            double sum=0;
            cout << "Enter an value and a unit (cm,m,in,ft) (To end the program, enter a value with 'd' as the unit. Avoid entering a unit of 'e' without a space.):\n";

            double val1=0;
            double val2=0;
            while(w==1)
            {
                cin >> init >> unit;
                if(unit!="m" && unit!="cm" && unit!="ft" && unit!="in" && unit!="d" ) //rejects unwanted units
                {
                    while(unit!="m" && unit!="cm" && unit!="ft" && unit!="in" && unit!="d")
                    {
                        cout << "Incorrect unit. Please enter a correct unit (m,cm,ft,in):\n";
                        cin >> unit;
                    }
                }
                if(unit=="m")
                {
                    cout << "\n" << init << "m\n";
                }
                if(unit=="cm")
                {
                    init=cm_m(init);
                    cout << "\n" << init << "m\n";
                }
                if(unit=="ft")
                {
                init=ft_m(init);
                cout << "\n" << init << "m\n";
                }
                if(unit=="in")
                {
                init=in_m(init);
                cout << "\n" << init << "m\n";
                }
                if(unit=="d") //d for "done"
                {
                    cout << "\nThe smallest number was: " << val2
                        << "\nThe largest number was: " << val1
                        << "\nThe sum of all numbers entered was: " << sum;
                        keep_window_open();
                        return 0;       
                }

                sum=init+sum;

                while(z<1) //This is set up so this 'while' loop is only used once to give initial values to val1 and val2
                {
                    cout << "\nSmallest so far." << '\t' << "Largest so far.\n";
                    val1=init;
                    val2=init;
                    ++z;
                }   
                if(init > val1)
                {
                    cout << "Largest so far.\n";
                    val1=init;
                }
                else if (init < val2)
                    {
                        cout << "Smallest so far.\n";
                        val2=init;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Probably related to how `1e3` is a double with the value `1000`. `e` is part of double literals

Comment: Define "totally breaks down".

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Doesn't really have anything to do with literals does it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the page explains what you put in your answer

Comment: @KillzoneKid: It's a co-incidence. Read the first line. _"Floating point literal defines a compile-time constant whose value is specified in the source file."_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I will give you plus for your answer it is much more thorough

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Thanks I will add it to my collection :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're performing so-called "formatted extraction" from a stream into a `double`, then into a `char`. When you give it `5` then `d`, these are valid inputs for `double` and `char` respectively. Other valid inputs for the `double` part would be `5.000` or `5.`.

However, `5e` is the start of a valid number in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), so it is taken *in entirety* for the `double` Then the stream state is set to "bad" because there is no exponent given (e.g. `5e42`). We never even get to the `char` part.

Because the stream state is now "bad", all your subsequent I/O operations fail too, which is probably what you are observing when "it totally breaks down".

```
Input          Extraction to double       Then extraction to char     Stream state
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5a             5                          a                           OK
5.000a         5.000                      a                           OK
5.a            5.                         a                           OK
5e             5e                         (n/a)                       BAD
5.e            5.e                        (n/a)                       BAD
5.000e         5.000e                     (n/a)                       BAD
5e42           5e42                       (n/a)                       OK*
5e42a          5e42                       a                           OK
```

<sup>(* but will be blocked waiting for you to enter something to put in the `char`)</sup>

So, yes, `e` is special.

**Always check the stream state after performing I/O.**

When the stream goes bad, you will probably want to clear the error state then prompt the user to try again from scratch.